# Max row required for each group

Tags: sql, oracle

There is 1 table wherein all these records are maintained for 1 employee. Due to one more column in this table which is not shown in this example the person has multiple rows for even 1 job , i.e. 2 rows for job J1 , 3 for Job J2 and again 2 rows for job J1 in order. The person switches from job J1 to J2 and then again J1.How to extract the required rows whenever a switch happens as I have to extract the max of each row when job is changed. I used group by in subquery of main query to extract the rows but then if the person switches back to same job J1 after going for J2 it doesn't work as it treats all the jobs in J1 in one group which is not correct. Please help me.

```
StDt             EdDt           Job      Required_Rows
1-Jan-21      31-Jan-21        J1          N
1-Feb-21      30-Jun-21        J1          Y
1-Jul-21      30-Jul-21        J2          N
1-Aug-21      15-Aug-21        J2          N
16-Aug-21     31-Aug-21        J2          Y
1-Sep-21      1-Nov-21         J1          N
2-Nov-21      31-Dec-21        J1          Y
```

Comment: You have a table for each user? That is very bad database design. Consider changing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12, you can use`MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY stDt
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ({- same* -} same )
  DEFINE
    same AS FIRST(job) = job
);
```

In earlier versions, you can use the `LEAD` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT StDt,
       EdDt,
       Job
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LEAD(job) OVER (ORDER BY StDt) AS next_job
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  next_job IS NULL
OR     next_job != job;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (StDt, EdDt, Job) AS
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', DATE '2021-01-31', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-02-01', DATE '2021-06-30', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-07-01', DATE '2021-07-31', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-01', DATE '2021-08-15', 'J2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-08-16', DATE '2021-08-31', 'J2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-09-01', DATE '2021-11-01', 'J1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-11-01', DATE '2021-12-31', 'J1' FROM DUAL
```

Both output:

> | STDT | EDDT | JOB |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-31 00:00:00 | J1 |
> | 2021-08-16 00:00:00 | 2021-08-31 00:00:00 | J2 |
> | 2021-11-01 00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 00:00:00 | J1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fe96f95f5f5a65b9df2c72a8e1a530bf)*

Comment: Hey Thanks. This works really fine. Also, how do we include if we want to include more column changes in this table like if with job we have to capture location changes as well in the same query which is present in the same table . I am currently using your LEAD query . Also, second part is if we have to pick changes from another table and show here as well. Please help. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AlkaOjha If you have a different problem then you can [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You are asking multiple questions there and they are out of scope for this question and it would be better for you to provide a proper [MRE] in a new question. It may be as simple as just including the `location` column in the `SELECT` clause (and/or `JOIN`ing the other table first) but without an example of your data it is difficult to answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks, I have asked another question as you suggested. Please see "Max value in record" question asked by me incase you know the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry the title is changed to "Select only rows where an attribute changes" .... Please help incase you know how to do it.

Comment: Hey, in this set of data what happens if there is a data where there is no change in job, how do I pull the max row in that case. We have both the types of data in which there is a change in job for some employees, where the solution you have suggested works but in case where there is no change I need to pick the max of those rows.

Comment: @AlkaOjha You can use exactly the same query [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7e5603216ac8b368cd7bd392aef4a880).